# Increase thickness of symbols in R plot

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to increase the thickness of the symbols in my plots?I'm trying to increases the thickness of the lines in a rectangle or square symbols. I know lwd changes the thickness of the line through the points but I don't see any parameters that correspond to changing the thickness of the shapes without changing the size.

Comment: not that I know of.  You could cheat by jittering/overplotting a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited: You could use `cex` to control the size of the points, and `lwd` to increase the line width e.g.:

```
set.seed(1); plot(runif(10), cex = 1.5, lwd = 2)
```

See `?par`. However, increasing `lwd` will increase the size of the points since the line undoubtedly becomes thicker.

Comment: "without changing the size"?

Answer (score 1):

`pt.lwd` is what you are probably looking for